Accessing StaticBigInt count of words
Let’s say I want to create custom Integer type. I would use StaticBigInt to initialize it as literal. Here’s an example from official documentation:
extension UInt256: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    public init(integerLiteral value: StaticBigInt) {
        precondition(
            value.signum() >= 0 && value.bitWidth <= 1 + Self.bitWidth,
            "integer overflow: '\(value)' as '\(Self.self)'"
        )
        self.words = Words()
        for wordIndex in 0..<Words.count {
            self.words[wordIndex] = value[wordIndex]
        }
    }
}

The issue appears when I want to initialise it with the same words as StaticBigInt have. I can’t find a way to get StaticBigInt’s words count. There is only subscript accessing certain word. It returns zero if the word is empty, but existing word also can be zero.
So how can I make this possible?
struct CustomInt: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    public var words: [UInt]

    public init(integerLiteral value: StaticBigInt) {
        words = []
        for i in 0..< value words count {
            words.append(value[i])
        }
    }
}

